# Problems with Randomized Guessing Game

Tags: python-3.x

this is my first post here so bear with me. I decided to take an online coding course to help me learn the basics of Python, up until now it's been great. Difficult, but manageable. Well, it appears I've hit a wall. I am trying to write a program that randomly generates a word from a wordlist.txt file then allow the user to guess letters in said word with a set amount of guesses.

'''

```
import random
def pick_word_from_file():
    file = open("wordlist.txt", 'r')
    words = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    word = random.choice(words).strip("\n")
    return word
    
word = pick_word_from_file()
hidden_word = len(word)
num_of_guesses = 5

print('Welcome to Guess a Letter!')
print('Your word has {} letters.'.format(hidden_word))

print('You have {} guesses left!'.format(num_of_guesses))

new_word = []

for i in range(hidden_word):
    new_word.append('_')
print(new_word)

while num_of_guesses > 0:
    guess = input('Take a guess!')
    if guess in word:
        num_of_guesses = num_of_guesses - 1
        pass
    else:
        num_of_guesses = num_of_guesses - 1
        print('Oof! looks like that letter is not in the word!')

 if num_of_guesses == 0:
     Print('All out of guesses!')
 '''
```

What I am currently struggling with is replacing the hashed out letter of the randomized word with the correct guess. Every time is a guess is correct it should output that letter in the correct space for the word.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem is storing the indices of each character in a dictionary like this.

```
>>> word = 'python'
>>> word_loc = {}
>>> for idx, char in enumerate(word):
...     word_loc[char] = word_loc.get(char, []) + [idx]
...
>>> word_loc
{'p': [0], 'y': [1], 't': [2], 'h': [3], 'o': [4], 'n': [5]}
```

Next, update each index accordingly when the guess is correct.

```
>>> while True:
...     guess = input('Take a guess!\n')
...     if len(guess) != 1:
...         print('Invalid guess!')
...     elif guess in word:
...         print('correct guess!')
...         for idx in word_loc[guess]:
...             new_word[idx] = guess
...         print(new_word)
...         if ''.join(new_word) == word:
...             print('Congratulations! You've guessed the word correctly!')
...             break
...     else:
...         num_of_guesses -= 1
...         print('Incorrect guess! Remaining attempts = {}'.format(num_of_guesses))
...         if num_of_guesses == 0:
...             print('You failed to guess the word! Aborting program!')
...             break
...
Take a guess!
s
Incorrect guess! Remaining attempts = 4
Take a guess!
r
Incorrect guess! Remaining attempts = 3
Take a guess!
p
correct guess!
['p', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Take a guess!
y
correct guess!
['p', 'y', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Take a guess!
c
Incorrect guess! Remaining attempts = 2
Take a guess!
h
correct guess!
['p', 'y', '_', 'h', '_', '_']
Take a guess!
n
correct guess!
['p', 'y', '_', 'h', '_', 'n']
Take a guess!
s
Incorrect guess! Remaining attempts = 1
Take a guess!
a
Incorrect guess! Remaining attempts = 0
You failed to guess the word! Aborting program!
```